# Free implementation of Elgamal

Tags: open-source, public-key-encryption, elgamal

I'm looking for free  implementations of the Elgamal encryption algorithm. As far as I can see, even though it's a widely known algorithm, there seems to be only two free implementations:

- [libgcrypt](http://www.gnu.org/software/libgcrypt/) supports Elgamal encryption
- [pycrypt](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/) has Elgamal

OpenSSL, beecrypt, Nettle do not implement Elgamal.

Are there any other free and well-tested Elgamal implementation that's missing from the list?

Answer (score 0):

[Crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com/) has [ElGamal support](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/struct_el_gamal.html).

I used Crypto++ symmetric cryptography some while ago, it seemed to be well-supported and well-tested (it has a unit-test named `ValidateElGamal()`).